# ErrorCode 87 in Event Viewer

Tags: windows-10, usb, bluetooth, event-log, event-viewer

On my Windows 10 sometimes I hear sound indicating that a device that was connected either via USB or Bluetooth was removed but I don't know which device was it and notifications pane doesn't have such information either.

Is that information available in either Event Viewer somehow or somewhere else in the system? How can I look for it?

edit>

I think I've tracked down the error in **Event Viewer** but I'm no sure what it means.

**Failed with 0x57 retrieving AppModel Runtime status for package Windows.**
[image]
**ErrorCode 87**
[image]

Comment: Yes, in System events.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko What do you mean by "System events" ? In Event Viewer somehow? How can I filter it out?

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/41475-disconnect-connect-events.html

Comment: Somehow I found an error in Event Viewer. I've added more info about it.

Comment: [Error Code 87](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) always refers to an incorrect parameter within an issued command

Comment: @JW0914 Is there any way to track down what command has caused this log message ?

Comment: More than likely, however I'm not that knowledgeable about the advanced functionality of Event Viewer. You may want to google the error message and reference Microsoft Docs for [Event Viewer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/host-integration-server/core/windows-event-viewer1), and you could also create a custom filter for that _Log Name_ to see if it occurs again.